# Adding the event to button in javascript (using the Flask)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using python Flask but is Javascript I am thinking. I try to follows the tutorial on this [site](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972).

There the guy has function such (Step 4):

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnSignUp').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/signUp',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Let me explain setups so far.

In body of html, I am having

```
    <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" 
    onclick="palValidateSignUp()">Sign up</button>
```

In the  of my page HTML, I have

```
<script src="../static/jquery.js">
function palValidateSignUp() 
{
  FUNCTION FROM TUTORIAL IN HERE
}
</script>
```

What I want is

- to click button.
- Button then call palValidateSignUp.
- PalValidateSignUp to call function above which does POST.

Do I needs to create new file(s)? Where I put code and what do I call it? I know this is easiest for many, just not for the me!

Comment: i cant understand what you are asking. the js file and function should be in the static and you should be able to load it. it looks for the buttonclick it self, but you putting another function in `onclick` may block it? remove the `onclick` part if you dont need it. or paste error's if you have any.

Comment: Not understanding myself :-(. Are you says the piece of code "$(function() {... " should be in the file by istelf? What I call this new file? I want to call the function button click palValidateSignUp (in html). Then, where I add function - and what's I calling the file? Thanks you for your comment! Maybe I not explains to good? Are you saying I create a .js file somewhere? When I clicks the button, I want function palValidateSignUp to be called and for code POST to works!

Comment: Thank you again Mr @senaps. I have edits the question - maybe peoples understanding better now?

Comment: where is the function placed ? is it in the template file? will you should avoid that, but for now, you are all set(i guess). remove the onclick part and test.

Comment: But my question asking is, where I place the code? At moment, I experiment with the code in `<head>` of page - I have button click palValidateSignUp in `<body>` then try to tell button onclick to go get palValidateSignUp - can do with silly alert box message, but not with these codes - i.e. long function. How does I call my POST function usings? Where I put file - what I call file? All these simple things for peoples who knows. Just want to simple call POST on the click button! Please, so sorry if question stupid!

Comment: @senaps - I redoes the qustion. I am thinking it easier to understand. Hopefully!

Comment: make sure you have included <script src="jquery.js"> before <script>Your function </script>; Else u will get error..

Comment: Yes, I am having that - thanks you!

Comment: Whats ur current status; are u able to work with the changes so far?

Comment: @PálTeleki I hope u understood my concern; its not about having jquery in your file; its also about where it is in ur code; that matters too..

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram Understand you. I have edit small. `<script src="../static/jquery.js"> function palValidateSignUp()`. Still not work! Where I put my POST function code? Does I creates new file? Does it do somewhere else in .html?

Comment: see if my answer helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just re-arranging your code and putting it as answer here since I feel that you sorely need a html boilerplate code;

I can't guarantee if it will work, I am just pointing you in the right path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title of Your Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="palValidateSignUp()">Sign up</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function palValidateSignUp() {
    $(function() {
      $('#btnSignUp').click(function() {

          $.ajax({
              url: '/signUp',
              data: $('form').serialize(),
              type: 'POST',
              success: function(response) {
                  console.log(response);
              },
              error: function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
              }
          });
      });
  });
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This work now! Thanking you most kindly. Problem was the simple, but stuck! :-) Gave you correct answer. Cannot the upvote to give :-( - not enough the reputation! When I gets more maybe? Tutorial not good however - other mistake! Not test! OK - will look again, but have learned!